# Jquery UI accordion custom icons loading but not appearing in div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I am having an issue getting my custom icons in my accordion to appear on page, they load, they toggle onclick from

```
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon iconClosed"></span> to `<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon iconOpen"></span>`
```

, they are appearing in devtools, but the span shows them as 0 x 0 px on the actual page. If I set the background image in mNavigation, the arrow loads fine. Here is my relevant code

CSS

```
   /*--------------jquery custom icons--------------*/
.iconClosed {
    background-image: url('/_img/mobile/mrightArrow.png') !important;
    width: 35px;
    height: 15px;
    background-position: 98% 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.iconOpen {
    background-image: url('/_img/mobile/mdownArrow.png') !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: 98% 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
var icons = {
  header: "iconClosed",
  activeHeader: "iconOpen"
};
$("#accordion").accordion({
    icons: icons,
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="mNavigation">  
            <ul  id="accordion">
                <li>
                    <h3><a href="#">Stories</a></h3>
                        <div class ="mNavigation" id = "Foo"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3><a href="#">Barristers</a></h3>
                        <div class ="mNavigation" id = "Foo"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3><a href="#">Dancing in the Dark</a></h3>
                        <div class ="mNavigation" id="Foo"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3><a href="#">Avocado</a></h3>
                        <div class ="mNavigation" id="Foo"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `<span>` tags won't obey a `width` or `height` property so you'll need to add `display:block` to your icon.

```
.ui-accordion-header-icon {
    display: block;
}
```

It looks like you want your icons to be inline so you should use `display:inline-block` instead.

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/97eP6/)**

Comment: Very much so, thank you. I haven't run into that issue ever before, but this solved it perfectly.